# An endless supply of 1's for securely overwriting and erasing a disk

Tags: hard-drive, data-transfer

I vaguely remember hearing about disk wiping, and that you have to flood the disk with zeros, flood it with ones, flood it with random data, and repeat this quite a few times. This is just a general question, as I am not going to have to wipe spy files or other top secret information off a disk. I figured I could use

`dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/diskname`

`dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/diskname`

But then, I realized that there wasn't (as far as I know) a file for infinite ones. Two questions... Is there either an alternative or a solution, and would the ones be necessary?

Comment: Just want to mention that with modern drives, a wipe with random and then wipe with zeros is plenty.  There's no reason to do a 7 pass, 5 pass, 3 pass.  http://www.anti-forensics.com/disk-wiping-one-pass-is-enough

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The file for endless ones is located in `/usr/bin/yes 1` - you can often use the backtick character ` to execute that program in place, but you could also set up a named pipe if you really wanted a place to get ones.

Rather than use dd - you might have much better luck with a tool designed specifically for the task.

- https://github.com/rentzsch/stressdrive - source code to verify 100% overwrite
- diskutil zeroDisk disk3
- diskutil secureErase 4 disk3

The level for secureErase can be 0-4 according to the [man page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/diskutil.8) and your taste for the number and types of overwrites.

Comment: I didn't think about using `yes`. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use Disk Utility to write random data 1, 3 or 7 times to the disk.  Just click on the disk you want to wipe, then Security Options.  You'll be prompted with a dialogue to select the amount of rewrites you want to use:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Disk Utility has an option to securely erase a hard drive using a standardized algorithm. Just navigate to the Erase panel and look for the button "Security Options...".